# PhoneGap + jQuery: How to access FileWriter.write inside a jQuery callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, callback

**I'm using Phone gap, see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter**

I'm trying to do this:

I'm passing a FileWriter (HTML5 Object) to a function.

I need to download a file and then use the writer to write to file, but ... how to access file writer from inside the callback ?

```
function onNotGotIntrattenimento() {
    sdcard.getFile("maiscai/intrattenimento.js", 
                   {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                    onCreatedIntrattenimentoWriter, onError);

}

function onCreatedIntrattenimentoWriter (intrattenimento_writer) {
    intrattenimento_writer.onwrite = onIntrattenimentoUpdated();
    downloadIntrattenimento(intrattenimento_writer);
}

function downloadIntrattenimento(intrattenimento_writer) {

    $.ajax({
        url: intrattenimento_link,
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        intrattenimento_writer.write(data);
    });
}
```

**How to cal intrattenimento_write.write methos inside the done callback ?!?!**

I receive an error

> 03-22 22:02:56.896: E/Web Console(27627): TypeError: Result of
>   expression 'intrattenimento_writer.write' [undefined] is not a
>   function. at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:62

Comment: Your code is correct - the intrattenimento_write parameter from the function can be used inside the callback - what is the problem ?

Comment: You have a typo - see the answer below

Comment: Already fixed, but the problem persists

Comment: Are u sure this object has "write" function ?

Comment: Your problem is NOT in the code you are showing us.  Are you sure you are passing an object to this function that has a valid `write` method?

Comment: YES ! http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter - And see other code I've add to my question

Comment: I just updated my answer below.  I think you might need to take another look at the PhoneGap documentation.  `intrattenimento_writer` doesn't seem to have a `write` method.  You first need to call `intrattenimento_writer.createWriter(...)`.

Comment: Yes, it's was the problem.
Please, clear the answer and I'll vote it up !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you have a spelling error?  You are missing the last 'r':

You have:

```
intrattenimento_write.write(data);
```

It should be:

```
intrattenimento_writer.write(data);
```

UPDATE: Now that you corrected the original question, my answer above doesn't make any sense any more.  However, the code you are now showing is absolutely correct.  You should have access to `intrattenimento_writer` just fine.

Are you sure your `intrattenimento_write` variable has a `write` function? If so, can you show the code that is associated with the function?

UPDATE 2:

I just looked at the PhoneGap documentiation you provided.  First let me say that I have absolutely no experience with PhoneGap, but from the docs it seem like you need to use the `createWriter` method on your `intrattenimento_write` object before you can use `write`.  Look at the example they are using:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    ...
    writer.write("some sample text");
}
```

Comment: UPDATE 2 it's the answer !